# Failed to build sample SDK add-on on Android 13 AOSP

Tags: android, android-soong, android-13

I'm trying to build my own SDK add-on from scratch, and attempt to comply with the sample in device/sample. Complying to the instructions in README.txt, I got following failure while building:

```
[100% 1/1] analyzing Android.bp files and generating ninja file at out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
cd "$(dirname "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i  "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --soong_o
ut "out/soong"     --out "out"     -o out/soong/build.ninja --globListDir build --globFile out/soong/globs-build.ninja -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list --available_env out/s
oong/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used.build Android.bp
error: prebuilts/module_sdk/conscrypt/current/Android.bp:20:1: dependency "art-bootclasspath-fragment" of "conscrypt-module-sdk_com.android.conscrypt-bootclasspath-fragment@current
" missing variant:
  apex:com.android.art
available variants:
  os:android,arch:common
error: prebuilts/module_sdk/conscrypt/current/Android.bp:20:1: dependency "prebuilt_art-bootclasspath-fragment" of "conscrypt-module-sdk_com.android.conscrypt-bootclasspath-fragmen
t@current" missing variant:
  apex:com.android.art
available variants:
  os:android,arch:common
10:34:20 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
```

Does anyone encounter the same issue? It would be appriciated if there's any workaround on this. Thanks.

Comment: I do encounter the same issue but I haven't found a solution for it yet.

Comment: So adding `$(call inherit-product, build/target/product/gsi_release.mk)` to the target makes the error go away but then I get `build/make/core/artifact_path_requirements.mk:30: warning:  build/make/target/product/generic_system.mk produces files outside its artifact path requirement. Allowed paths are root/*, system/*`

Comment: Although adding `gsi_release.mk` is not really supposed to be the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit `build/make/target/product/sdk_phone_x86_64.mk` (or your device target file) and add following line at the end:

```
MODULE_BUILD_FROM_SOURCE := true
```

For me, that solved the error and the build now starts.

You can view my product repository (you can drop it in your source tree and use `lunch aosp_sdk_phone_x86_64-eng`) to have this change as well:

https://git.halogenos.org/halogenOS/android_product_halogenOS/

Comment: Your solution works like a charm. It solves the problem on SDK building as well. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. You're welcome.

Comment: Build has gone through but sdk-repo-linux-system-images-eng.[username].zip not being generated.