Errors when building sdk-addon in recent AOSP (Android 14)
I am trying to build sdk addon in AOSP with Android 14 branch. the only example I came across is in the device/sample folder of AOSP tree. In README.txt, it says
To build the add-on:
    lunch sample_addon-userdebug
    m sdk_addon

But when I ran m sdk_addon, I got the following errors. It seems the sample was created from very old Android version. Can someone show me the updated example or instructions? Thanks!
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
cd "$(dirname "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/host/linux-x86/bin/s
oong_build")" && cd / && env -i  "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --soong_out "out/soong"     --out "out"  
   -o out/soong/build.ninja --bazel-mode --globListDir build --globFile out/soong/globs-build.ninja -t -l 
out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list --available_env out/soong/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soo
ng/soong.environment.used.build Android.bp
error: packages/modules/RuntimeI18n/apex/Android.bp:67:1: dependency "art-bootclasspath-fragment" of "i18n
-bootclasspath-fragment" missing variant:
  os:android,arch:common,apex:com.android.art
available variants:
  os:android,arch:common
error: packages/modules/RuntimeI18n/apex/Android.bp:67:1: dependency "prebuilt_art-bootclasspath-fragment"
 of "i18n-bootclasspath-fragment" missing variant:
  os:android,arch:common,apex:com.android.art
available variants:
  os:android,arch:common
14:06:11 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (35 seconds) ####


I tried to switch to Android 11, but then m sdk_addon give another error:

FAILED: ninja: 'images/source.properties', needed by 'out/host/linux-x86/obj/SDK_ADDON/platform_library_int
ermediates/platform_library-eng.dev01-linux-x86-img', missing and no known rule to make it
20:13:50 ninja failed with: exit status 1



I found this solution for Android 13 solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73825932/failed-to-build-sample-sdk-add-on-on-android-13-aosp

new user here. I have to make a answer although I think this ought to be just a comment because it requires 50 reputation to add a comment.
I am also working on creating an SDK add-on because my work creates a custom system service and its manager, and I have to expose the manager to my app developed in Android Studio.
This topic is rarely talked about based on Google result, but here's what I found so far:

Samsung distribute their custom SDK via download and instruct the developer to copy their library into the app. https://developer.samsung.com/mobile/galaxy-sdk-getting-started.html#:~:text=library%20to%20Android-,studio,-To%20use%20a

Someone on this site shared their approach to this problem and asked about an issue further down the road. You may just follow what they've done. Adding custom SDK based on Andorid version 11 to Android studio

There is a guide on GitHub by profusion in great detail. https://github.com/profusion/android-sdk-addon-example?tab=readme-ov-file


I haven't tried any of these, please just take them for your information.
I don't think this answer will solve your problem right away, but at least I happen to come across your question relatively recent. You just asked 2 days ago at time of writing :)
Update:
Following #3 based on OP's comment,

I did try #3 you mentioned, but unfortunatelly the example no longer worked since Android 12, there are quite a few build errors including this one. I did make some workaround to make it working for Android 13. Coming back to this issue, I found the solution here helped: stackoverflow.com/questions/73825932/…

The answer from the link uses a line
MODULE_BUILD_FROM_SOURCE := true

It resolves the build error encountered, but I don't think my module is defined correctly and the build system cannot find my module to link against.

In file included from build/make/core/main.mk:1446:
In file included from build/make/core/Makefile:7117:
build/make/core/tasks/sdk-addon.mk:45: error: Unknown or unlinkable module: com.my.manager. Requested by device/my/mycar/mycar.mk.
11:08:21 ckati failed with: exit status 1


thanks for the info. I did try #3 you mentioned, but unfortunatelly the example no longer worked since Android 12, there are quite a few build errors including this one. I did make some workaround to make it working for Android 13.
Coming back to this issue, I found the solution here helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73825932/failed-to-build-sample-sdk-add-on-on-android-13-aosp
